# How to change relayhost for mail server

Tags: zimbra, email-server

Today I configure outgoing mail for my zimbra mail server like this [tutorial](http://www.smtp2go.com/docs/zimbra_mta/), however I made a typo error when setting up relayhost, so when I run the command:
`postmap hash:/opt/zimbra/conf/relay_password`
 It threw the error:
`fatal: myhostname and relayhost parameter settings must not be identical: mail.mydomain.com`
. The reason is because I set relayhost like that:
`zmprov ms mail.mydomain.com zimbraMtaRelayHost mail.mydomain.com`. So what can I do to change my relay host and what exactly I can do to overcome this error?

Answer (score 2):

After an hour searching, I have solved my problem by easy command:

```
postconf -e 'relayhost = smtp.example.com'
```

this will override the relayhost that I've set before.